# Double direction scrolling collectionView with multiple sections data issue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a double direction scrolling collectionView with 50 sections, 10 items per section and 3 showing cells per section and filling the collectionView with the same data array.
the problem is the collectionView duplicate data in every section and I want to show different data in appearing sections to the user.
Any help please! 
this is my code:

```
 func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 50
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: contentCellIdentifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! UserCollectionCell

    cell.userImageView.kf.setImage(with: URL.init(string:  String().loadCorrectUrl(url:firebaseUsers[indexPath.row].image))) 
    cell.userNameLabel.text=firebaseUsers[indexPath.row].name
    if(selectedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ){
        cell.userBackgroudView.isHidden=false
    }
    else{
        cell.userBackgroudView.isHidden=true
    }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Comment: how you achieved both direction scrolling without another collectionview

Answer (score 1):

Implement `prepareForReuse` in `UserCollectionCell` and clear the imageView and label text to prevent showing duplicate data on scroll

```
class UserCollectionCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.userImageView.image = nil
        self.userNameLabel.text = nil
    }
}
```

Hope it helps